# Special characters in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, special-characters, ruby-1.8.7

Can any one suggest me any gem or a way to solve the special characters issue occurring in ruby 1.8.7 and rails 3.2.13.
I want to replace the special characters instead of removing.

I have tired using iconv gem. It works for some special characters alone.

Thanks..

Comment: What are the special characters, please post your code.

Comment: @31piy: im having special characters like "Çi, �z" on my page. while using iconv in terminal it works fine if the same is used in page, <% @a = Iconv.iconv("ASCII//translit", "utf-8", 'Çii') %> it shows ?i